# Let $A$ be a square matrix such that $A(I-A)=I$, prove $A^2-I$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a square matrix such that $A(I-A)=I$, prove $A^2-I$ is invertible.

$A^2-I=(A-I)(A+I)$, clearly $A-I$ is invertible, but how do I prove that $A+I$ is also invertible?

Comment: You just have to check that -1 is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is, $A^2 - A + I = 0$.

This concludes that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $p(x) = x^2 - x + 1$.

Then finding the inverse of $A^2 - I$ is equivalent to finding the inverse of $x^2 - 1$ modulo $p(x)$.

That is, the inverse of $x - 2$ modulo $x^2 - x + 1$. Some calculation gives $\dfrac{-x - 1}{3}$.

Verify: $(x - 2) (-x - 1) = -x^2 + x + 2 \equiv 3 \pmod{p(x)}$.

Therefore, $\dfrac{-A - I}{3}$ is exactly the inverse of $A^2 - I$.

Comment: I didn't learn minimal polynomials... is there any way to do it without this?

Comment: @KantigShoter You don’t need to be afraid about this. In this case there’s noting complicated about the minimal polynomial. You can just verify whether if $(A^2 - I) ((-A - I) / 3) = I$ holds, by using $A^2 - A + I = 0$ multiple times (multiply it by $A$ and do similar things as division of polynomials).

Comment: @KantigShoter The minimal polynomial just gives a general thought and a computational approach about it. But the verification is simple and has nothing to do with the main ideas with minimal polynomials.

Comment: I came by the same answer but using a different method and missing the factor of $\frac13$. What am missing?

Comment: @CyclotomicField Simple. Your calculation goes wrong in somewhere. Mine is wrong initially, too. Then I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

We have $A^2=A-I$ and $A^3=A^2-A=-I$, so that
$$
(A^2-I)(A+I)=A^3+A^2-A-I=A^3-2I=-3I.
$$
Hence $A+I$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A^2=A-I$ we have $A^3=A^2-A = -I$. Since we have a reduction rule $A^3$ we conjecture the inverse is of the form $xA+yI$ for some scalars $x$ and $y$. Now calculating $$(A^2-I)(xA+yI)=x(A^2-I)A+y(A^2-I) \\= xA^3+yA^2-xA+yI \\= yA^2-xA+(-y-x)I$$

And comparing $yA^2-xA$ to $-A^2+A$ so we choose $x=y=-1$ which gives us that $yA^2-xA+(-y-x)I = -A^2+A+2I=3I$. This shows that $(-A-I)/3$ is the inverse of $A^2-I$.